# startup.py for settings in QGIS

Tags: coordinate-system, pyqgis, startup.py

I want to use the QGIS startup.py to set up some configurations. I want to set the following options in the startup.py:

- CRS for project - use a default CRS: EPSG 25833
- CRS for layer - default CRS for layers EPSG: 25833
- use roxy for web access

Therefore I use the following code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsSettings, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

# set CRS for projects  EPSG:25833 
QgsProject.instance().setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:25833'))

# set CRS for new layers EPSG:25833
QgsSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehavior', 'useProject')
QgsSettings().setValue('/Projections/layerDefaultCrs', 'EPSG:25833')
QgsSettings().setValue('/Projections/projectDefaultCrs', 'EPSG:25833')

# enable proxy for web access
QgsSettings().setValue('/Proxy/proxyEnabled', True)


# necessary, otherwise the window for saving projects appears at startup
QgsProject.instance().setDirty(False)
```

The settings for the proxy and new layers work, but it does not work for new projects. New projects dont use the CRS EPSG 25833

Comment: Why do you want to do that with PyQGIS ? I think you can just customize your global settings, either with GUI or by changing the QGIS3.ini file directly. I didn't check, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes that's right, that's also the way I currently use. But I am preparing a QGIS update in my company and in this context I want to run all necessary settings via Startup.py. With the help of Startup.py I create for example additional functions for the users and I don't want to have two files that have to be exchanged at the user. For this I want to transfer all settings from the qgis_global_settings.ini into the Startup.py. Most of it works, only the CRS for projects does not.

Answer (score 2):

Correct parameter is `defaultProjectCrs`